# How to include my javascript again after using ajax to populate a modal

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, modal-dialog, popup

I am building an interactive map. Upon click of a certain svg path / group I want to open a modal/popup with information in it. The information will be populated by a Wordpress post.

Unfortunately, once I've opened the modal window the js no longer is included. I don't want to refresh the page, I just want to call the js on click of the modal trigger.

SVG path trigger:

```
    <path id="modal-trigger" class="st4 lot-144 modal-trigger" onclick="term_ajax_get(<?php $lotTitle = get_page_by_title('Lot 1', '', 'lot' ); echo $lotTitle->ID; ?>);" d="M264.819 444.995l-3.505 29.135-39.031-4.942 3.833-29.093z"/>
```

JS included in a PHP file

```
    function term_ajax_get(post_slug) {
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );?>';

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {"action": "load-lot", slug: post_slug },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            jQuery(".lot-details").html('');
            jQuery(".lot-details").html(response);
        }
    });

}
```

JS for the modal:

```
    var lotModal = document.querySelector('.lot-modal');
    var trigger = document.querySelector('.modal-trigger');
    var closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-modal');

    function toggleModal() {
        lotModal.classList.toggle('modal-is-visible');
    }

    function windowOnClick(event) {
        if (event.target === lotModal) {
            toggleModal();
        }
    }

    trigger.addEventListener('click', toggleModal);
    closeBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleModal);
    window.addEventListener('click', windowOnClick);
```

Pease let me know if there's anything else that you want me to add to make it easier to understand.

Comment: You might consider just using event delegation instead